# Carousel dinámico con React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Quiero hacer un carousel dinámico que me traiga las imágenes de una api. Lo estoy haciendo con hooks, pero mi problema es que las imágenes no se están mostrando cómo deberían. Después de consumir la api, hago un `.map()` dentro del cuerpo del carousel.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Dónde o cómo debería consumir la api?, al parecer del modo que lo estoy haciendo esta mal, pero tampoco sé como seria la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Aquí mi código:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

const SliderSlick = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [nav1, setNav1] = useState();
  const [nav2, setNav2] = useState();
  const slider1 = useRef(null);
  const slider2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/user/nekomata1037/animelist/all")
      .then( response => response.json())
      .then(data  => setData(data.anime));
      setNav1(slider1.current);
      setNav2(slider2.current);
    }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ }}>
      <Slider className="mainSlider" asNavFor={nav2} ref={slider1}>
        {data.length > 0 && data.map(anime => (
          <img key={anime.mal_id} src={anime.image_url}></img>
        ))}
      </Slider>

      <Slider
        asNavFor={nav1}
        ref={slider2}
        slidesToShow={3}
        swipeToSlide={true}
        focusOnSelect={true}
      >
        {data.length > 0 && data.map(anime => (
          <img key={anime.mal_id} src={anime.image_url}></img>
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SliderSlick;
```

Comment: *las imágenes no se están mostrando como deberían* ¿Cómo se están mostrando? Esto podría ayudarnos a conocer qué está pasando.

Comment: una debajo de otra, son 300 imagenes, asi que estoy haciendo un carousel doble, de modo que el foco de la imagen de arriba se corresponda con los item del minicarousel de abajo. en este sentido son 600 imagenes una debajo de la otra, en lugar de mostrarse de forma lateral, quiero algo asi;  http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/

Comment: Probablemente no tenga relación, pero [en los ejemplos](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/simple-slider) veo que todos tienen un div dentro. ¿hace alguna diferencia si dejas tus tags `<img>` dentro de un `<div>`? si no, ¿podrías agregar un pantallazo de cómo se muestran las imágenes?

Comment: [Acabo de probar tu código](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-forked-de1jx?file=/index.js) usando como base [el playground](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick#playground) del proyecto y no parece que esté dando algún problema, a menos que esperes otro comportamiento en el carrusel.

Comment: en este vinculo se encuentran 3 capturas de pantalla, en la primera el carousel se muestra demasiado grande que abarca toda la pantalla y mas, en el segundo se muestra el segundo carousel con imagenes pequeñas una encima de la otra, y en la tercera imagenen, es un ejemplo de como me gustaria que quedara:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n6R_9VWB1Gu5N-RJGk85IYnovCFOyyNG?usp=sharing